# Implementing Facebook Pixel using Angular 10 ssr

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I've been trying to implement Facebook pixel in my project angular version 10 server side rendering by copy-paste this code in my index.html

```
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '{your-pixel-id-goes-here}');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
  </script>
```

at the first load after cleaning the cache it works fine on my homepage but when reload the page or goto another page it give me : No pixels found